# Abstract method inside abstract constructor

Tags: c++, class, abstract, virtual-functions, pure-virtual

I was wondering why can't i create something like this ? :

```
class Abstract_object
{
protected:
    virtual void _initialize() = 0;

public:
    Abstract_object()
    {
        _initialize();
    }
};

class Object : public Abstract_object
{
protected:
    void _initialize()
    {
         std::cout << "Initate client !" << std::endl;
    }

public:
    Object () : Abstract_object()
    {
        
    }
};

int main()
{
    Object* tmp = new Object();

    return (0);
}
```

When i try to compile it, i recieved a unresolved external symbol, which i quite don't understand where it came from : the definition of _initialize is indeed found in the children ... Someone can explain to me what is happening ? =)

i have tried to call _initiate inside the children class, and it did work as intended. But i will have to create multiple class enhancing Abstract class, and i do not want to call _initiate inside each one of them, so i'm looking for a turnaround, if someone have it =)

Thank you guys ! =)

This is the error i got when compiling this :
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall Abstract_object::_initialize(void)" (?_initialize@Abstract_object@@MAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Abstract_object::Abstract_object(void)" (??0Abstract_object@@QAE@XZ)

Comment: Are you trying to program C++ like it's C#? In C++ we now almost never need to use `new`. C++ is not C#.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor there is used the function _initialize

```
Abstract_object()
{
    _initialize();
}
```

Though it is a pure virtual function nevertheless you need to define it for the class `Abstract_object`. For example write after the class definition

```
void Abstract_object::_initialize()
{
    //...some code
}
```

Comment: Yes, thats' exactly the question : is it possible to call a virtual function inside an abstract constructor ? I have defined it inside the children definition

Comment: @Hyarius It is possible to call it. The virtual function of the base class will be called.

Comment: Yes, so it's impossible to call it in the constructor AND having it pure abstract. I can have it virtual but not abstract

Comment: @Hyarius There is no such a notion as the abstract function. There are abstract class and virtual function.

Comment: what "abstract method" don't exist ?

Comment: @Hyarius In C++ there is no such a notion.

Comment: In C++, an abstract method is just another way of describing the characteristics of a pure virtual function. Both just mean a method with no implementation provided that needs to be implemented in a sub-class before the class can actually be instantiated.

Comment: @Hyarius Even if you could get the code to compile, it simply can't work the way you want. You can't call an overridden child method from a base class constructor.

Comment: @Hyarius As I have written in C++ there is no such a term.

Comment: Thank, that's the awnser i wanted =) You simply can't call a abstract method inside the constructor of said abstract class. Wasted 1h on this problem, i don't need to search more ^^ Thanks =)